# How to get the last ID of the table

Tags: php, pdo

I'm implementing a code that gets the current ID of a current portfolio and make previous and next button to navigate through the next and previous images. The IDs are like 1,3,5,7 etc, not consecutive. I would like to know how to disable the "next" link when I reach the las ID in the table.

```
<?php

foreach($connection->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = (select min(id) from table where id > '.$myid.')') as $row) {

}
foreach($connection->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = (select max(id) from table where id < '.$myid.')') as $row1) {

}

        echo "<a class='anterior' href='http://miweb.com/proyecto/id/".$row1['id']."'>Previous</a>";

?>
<a class="siguiente" href="http://miweb.com/proyecto/id/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Next</a>
```

Comment: not the standard pagination approach

Comment: Its not a pagination right.

Answer (score 0):

That approach looks like very original crunch. You can use for pagination good practice with using `LIMIT`. For example, for MySQL:

```
$currentPage = 10;
$pageSize = 100;

// Display current page data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT :offset :pagesize";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
    ':offset' => $pageSize * $currentPage,
    ':pagesize' => $pageSize,
]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($data);

// Display Next button
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `table`";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if ($pageSize * ($currentPage + 1) < $count) {
    echo '<a href="...' . ($currentPage + 1) . '...">Next</a>';
}
```